# Durandal SPA splash with percentage

Tags: durandal, single-page-application, hottowel

How to show the loading indicator with actual percentage in durandal SPA splash screen.

I am using HotTowel SPA template.

```
<div id="applicationHost">
        <div class="splash">
          <div class="message">
              Durandal Starter Project
          </div>
          <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin active"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you consider progress.  Durandal is using require.js under to the covers to dynamically load in javascript files so when you first start your project and load the main.js, require is doing the work of finding all your requested js files and loading them.  If you want to show the progress of that it might be tricky.  Here is a link to a google group discussion about tapping into requirejs loading process:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/JX-9bHP1BBo

This approach would only be useful if you are not using a compiled version of your site.  On the [durandal docs](http://durandaljs.com/docs.html) page there is a whole section about optimizing your project by combining all your js and html views into a single file that gets loaded at startup and removes the need to show progress of file loading at all.

If you have some long running processes that must be completed before you show the user your  project you can do this in the activate function of your shell module.  I have done this using nested [jquery promise objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and the [blockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).  What you have to do is return a promise from your activate function, this will cause durandal to wait till you finish your startup code before it loads your shell ui.  In that promise you use [jquery's when/then](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) functions to call any number of other functions which also must return promises.  For each of those functions that get called pass in as a parameter a function to update your progress ui. here is a sample of my shells activate function

```
function activate() {

    var def = new $.Deferred();
    try {

    var messageBoxHtml = [
    '<div class="messageBox">',
        '<div class="modal-header">',
            '<h3>Processing</h3>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="modal-body">',
             '<p class="message" id="blockMessageTag">Processing request, please wait...</p>',
             '<div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">',
                 '<div id="blockMessageTagProgress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 0%;"></div>',
             '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="modal-footer">',
        '</div>',
    '</div>'
    ].join('\n');

    $.blockUI({ message: messageBoxHtml });

    var updateMain = function (msg) {
        def.notify(msg);
    };

    var totalProgress = 0;
    def.progress(function (newMessage) {
        logger.log("Boot Progress", "shell", newMessage);
        $("#blockMessageTag").text(newMessage + "...");
        totalProgress++;
        $("#blockMessageTagProgress").width((totalProgress * 25) + '%');
    });

    $.when(module1.dowork(updateMain), module2.dowork(updateMain))
    .done(function () {
        $.unblockUI();
        router.map([
            { route: 'Home', moduleId: 'views/myhome', title: 'Home' },
        ]).mapUnknownRoutes('views/Common/404', 'not-found')
          .activate().done(function () {
              def.resolve();
          }).fail(function (xh, status, msg) {
              logger.log(msg, "Shell Startup Failure", xh);
              $("#blockMessageTag").text("Failure: Check Console Log For Details - 1");
              $("#blockMessageTagProgress").width('0%');
              def.fail();
          });
    }).fail(function (xh, status, msg) {
        logger.log(msg, "Shell Startup Failure", xh);
        $("#blockMessageTag").text("Failure: Check Console Log For Details - 2");
        $("#blockMessageTagProgress").width('0%');
        def.fail();
    });
}
catch (ex) {
    logger.log(ex.message, "Shell Startup Failure", ex);
    $("#blockMessageTag").text("Failure: Check Console Log For Details - 3");
    $("#blockMessageTagProgress").width('0%');
    def.fail();
}
return def.promise();
```

}

All the module1.dowork function must also return a promise like so:

```
function (uiMsgBox) {

var def = new $.Deferred();

uiMsgBox('Starting Process');

try {
    //do whatever work you need to do here
    uiMsgBox('Process Complete');
    def.resolve(jsret);
} catch (error) {
    def.reject();
}

return def.promise();
```

};

Each call to the updateMain function you pass into your long running functions (module1.dowork and module2.dowork) will call notify on the promise your returned to durandal.  Notify will cause the progress function to be called and update your progress UI.  I kind of cheated and just hard coded the progress bar intervals.  The bar starts with 0% width and is change on every call by incrementing the totalProgress value by 1 and multiplying that by the correct percentage for the number of expected calls.  Each of the dowork methods should call the update progress ui twice so a total of 4 calls which makes the progess increment 25, (100 / 4).  You would need to adjust as needed.